# IDLE (Python GUI) 2.7.8 stop working on windows7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

My Python GUI don't open anymore!

I know there are other question in this topic, but I couldn't solve mine!

I try uninstalling it and the install it, but it didn't open.

I run C:\python27\python.exe -m idlelib.idle in cmd to find the error, here is the cmd output,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\run.py", line 5, in <module>
    import socket
  File "D:\python\lib\socket.py", line 8
    c, addr = s.accept() # Establish connection with client.
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

then IDLE open with an subprocess startup error:

```
IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start a subprocess or personal firewall is blocking the connection.
```

I also add TCL_LIBRARY to indicate the Python path C:\Python27\tcl\tcl8.5 to both user and system variable, but it didn't solve my problem!

So, how can i make my IDLE work again?

Comment: What is `D:\python\lib` doing on your path there? That `socket.py` file is invalid and breaking your Python setup.

Comment: I remember having this issue in my early days with Python. I just restarted my IDLE and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, thanks. I add this folder to my pythonpath to put my own library here! and socket.py has some problem, I remove it and now it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `D:\python\lib\socket.py` is *not* part of the standard library, but is being imported  instead of the normal module. The file is also broken, breaking your Python setup in multiple way.s

Rename it or remove the whole directory from `PYTHONPATH` configuration variable.